# Amazon web service as Rails hosting, possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to use Amazon web service to host a Rails application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should be able to set that up in several different ways on AWS.

Since you can configure an EC-2 instance much like a dedicated server, you can install any software you want and configure it to your needs.

There are some nice ruby tools here:
http://amazon-ec2.rubyforge.org/

Also 37 signals is on AWS - http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/37signals/

I recommend a simple Amazon Linux AMI Micro instance EBS backed to get started on the free tier.
http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 1):

This more of an Updated Answer.

You can use Elastic BeanStalk for Ruby deployment using Passenger. Checkout the links AWS [Elastic Beanstalk Runs Ruby and Integrates with Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/11/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-runs-ruby-and-integrates-with-amazon-vpc/) and [AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Ruby Support and VPC Integration](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/11/aws-elastic-beanstalk-ruby-support-and-vpc-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Tom mentioned, a simple EBS AMI should be enough to get started. At BitNami we have created  Ruby on Rails AMIs and [make them available for free](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack)   We also [offer a hosting service on top of Amazon](http://bitnami.org/cloud) that you can combine with the [AWS free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free) service to basically get free server for 1 year (618Mb RAM, 30gb) which is more than enough for development and light hosting.